Decoding UTM tags in data received from CTE
During the execution of the request, I receive data about the UTM-campaign. Some of the data is missing, and I substitute a NULL value (such a requirement), the other part of the data is given in 2 states - decoded and encoded.
HELP ME to build function that can check result of utm_campaign and decode only encoded rows!
with fb_name as

    (select 
        fabd.ad_date,
        'Facebook Ads' as media_source,
        fc.campaign_name,
        fa.adset_name,
        coalesce (fabd.spend, 0) as spend,
        coalesce (fabd.impressions, 0) as impressions,
        coalesce (fabd.reach, 0) as reach,
        coalesce (fabd.clicks, 0) as clicks,
        coalesce (fabd.leads, 0) as leads,
        coalesce (fabd.value, 0) as value,
        fabd.url_parameters 
        from facebook_ads_basic_daily fabd
        left join facebook_campaign fc  on fabd.campaign_id = fc.campaign_id 
        left join facebook_adset fa on fabd.adset_id  = fa.adset_id ),
        
    g_name as 
    (select
        gabd.ad_date,
        'Google Ads' as media_source,
        gabd.campaign_name,
        gabd.adset_name,
        coalesce (gabd.spend, 0) as spend,
        coalesce (gabd.impressions, 0) as impressions,
        coalesce (gabd.reach, 0) as reach,
        coalesce (gabd.clicks, 0) as clicks,
        coalesce (gabd.leads, 0) as leads,
        coalesce (gabd.value, 0) as value,
        gabd.url_parameters
        from google_ads_basic_daily gabd 
    
        union all
        
    select * from fb_name)
    
select 
    ad_date,
    case 
        when lower(substring(url_parameters,'utm_campaign=([^&#$]+)')) = 'nan' then null
        else lower(substring(url_parameters,'utm_campaign=([^&#$]+)'))
        end as utm_campaign,
    sum(spend) as total_spend,
    sum(impressions) as total_impressions,
    sum(clicks) as total_clicks,
    sum(value) as total_value,
    case when sum (impressions)>0 then concat(round((sum(clicks)::numeric/sum(impressions))*100,2), ' %') end as ctr,
    case when sum (clicks)>0 then concat(round((sum(spend)::numeric/sum(clicks)), 2), ' USD') end as cpc,
    case when sum (impressions)>0 then concat(round(((sum(spend)::numeric*1000)/sum(impressions)), 2), ' USD') end as cpm,
    case when sum (spend)>0 then concat(round(((sum(value)::numeric - sum(spend))/sum(spend))*100,2), ' %') end as romi
from 
    g_name
group by 1,2
order by 1;


I tried using AI but it doesn't help me with the problem....

Welcome to SO!  Here are a few suggestions to improve your question:

Some aspects of the question could use clarification.  "execution of the request".  What is this request?
When asking data/query related questions, it's helpful to provide examples  of underlying tables and data.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043162/how-to-query-data-from-sql-server for an example of this.
Be specific about what you're trying to accomplish.  "check result of utm_campaign" is unclear.  Providing your inputs and then examples of expected/desired output will make things much clearer.
Thi

